# Question is no longer reproducible, but the answer still has value

Tags: discussion, specific-question, minimal-reproducible-example

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3), which is often used as a duplicate target in [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py), is no longer reproducible.

What changed:
In discord.py version 1.7.3, the bot will no longer respond to a message with content `$test1`. This is the same behaviour as in discord.py 2.0. However, the answer still has value as it applies to both cases.

Why it changed:
Discord [recently made](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ) message content a "priveleged intent". For most discord.py devs, that means that you have to explicitly "subscribe" to these outside the code. Inside the code, discord.py 1.7.3 would automatically subscribe you to this intent, so it worked previously. Discord.py 2.0 did not automatically subscribe you to the event, prompting the aforementioned question.

Editing the question would require changing the intent of the original poster, to my understanding, but would rectify the problem.

Another alternative I see would be to make a Q&A pair, with both being [CWs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354). I could rewrite the question and copy the answer (with attribution), but I'm not sure on the etiquette of this.

My worry with leaving the question as-is is that the number of duplicate questions has seen a significant uptick since discord made their change, but the number of views on the question hasn't.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: *"Question is no longer reproducible, but the answer still has value"* - Okay? The answer is still there, why do you need to do anything? What makes it a problem?

Comment: Why/how is it no longer reproducible? Was it reproducible at the time the question was posted? If so, what changed?

Comment: @Makyen Yes, it was reproducible at the time it was posted. Discord made message_content a "privileged intent", and now one must explicitly subscribe to the intent in all versions of discord.py. Previously it was only discord.py>=2.0 where this was required.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine As it stands, I believe the question being no longer reproducible makes it harder to find for users facing this problem. There has been a significant uptick in duplicate questions where this question is the dupe target, but not a significant increase in views on the dupe target.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs - If questions today are being marked as a duplicate of a question, that cannot be reproduced today, then those closures are improper. Why does anything have to be done to the existing legacy question?

Comment: When a new high quality question comes along and attracts a high quality answer prior to closure, it can become the new dupe target. Until then, as long as the answers there still help the people being pointed to it... i don't see a reason to change course.

Comment: What do you mean by *"no longer reproducible"*? Are all *discord.py* files updated automatically? Aren't there any (official) archives with older versions? Are there some network or distributed system dependencies? Can you elaborate?

Comment: So you mean that the answer still stands but the part about it not being needed for version 1.7.3 is now wrong (Possibly because of some changes in the API that the package calls)? Why not simply edit both the question and answer and simply remove the mention of any versions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've edited this into my question. Please let me know if it makes sense

Comment: To be clear: The change was in the discord *server* setup, so that using the discord.py *client* libraries leads to different behaviour even though the client itself wasn't changed?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, the behaviour in version 1.7.3 was changed even though the client itself was not changed.

Comment: But is the problem not reproducible? It sounds more like the original, working code (v1.7.3 in March 2022) will no longer work in some circumstances but the problem that's being asked about is exactly the same (code that's broken in v2.0). Right?

Comment: @Laurel Indeed, the problem is exactly the same in v2.0. The same code in v1.7.3 does not work unless the same solution is applied.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I submitted [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32690585) to remove the mention of versions but it was rejected (even though it is tangential to the actual problem). Oh well

Comment: The reviewers mistook what you meant, anyway have you tested that code with an unverified bot (It might work with them as it is mentioned the update only affects verified bots)? You should also get a consensus in the meta post here before editing (Someone here with edit privileges might even make the edit themselves). Update your question here so that it is more clear ("_Question is no longer reproducible_" is incorrect, you can still reproduce the problem) Try posting an answer proposing what you plan to do.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It does affect unverified bots - in fact most people have unverified bots. The way it would be solved for unverified bots is the solution in the post. For verified bots they have to request it from Discord and get approved before they can subscribe to the intent. I'll edit my post to make what you mentioned clearer

Comment: Let me try to rephrase do you need to use the solution in the answer even for unverified bots in v1.7.3? From what I read of the docs v1.7.3 automatically used the message content intent, v2.0 stopped doing that and intents needed to be specified explicitly. If this still stands the question can stay the same.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat In 1.7.3, the code automatically requests the message content intent. However, if the user has not enabled it in their developer portal, the bot will not receive the intent. This is because it has become a privileged intent. In discord.py 2.0, the code does not automatically request the message content intent, so the behaviour hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's truly not possible for users to reproduce the issue (e.g. if this is a forced change made on a service end by Discord, and even users who don't change/update anything in their code will be unable to reproduce it), then you should close the question as not reproducible, because that's the most accurate representation of the current state of affairs.

If the issue *is* reproducible by users who manage to still use an old version of a library or something like that (I'm not familiar with Discord development or Python, so I don't know if this is possible based on your description of the issue) then it's not really "no longer reproducible"... it's just a behavior that has changed in a new version and it should remain open (perhaps with an edit to clarify the version of the library, since that's relevant).

---

Questions that are closed don't automatically disappear if they have upvoted or accepted answers. The question will still be discoverable via search and can still be voted up (and the same goes for the answer).

If you want to go the extra mile, you could either comment on or edit the question itself to include a blurb that mentions the breaking change causing the issue to be no longer reproducible.

Comment: The issue is reproducible from what I understand only change is that now the issue is also there for the older versions of the library whereas previously it was only for newer versions.